# Icon InstallShield Limited Edition 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, installshield, desktop

I have just installed InstallShield 2015 because I need to create an installer for my C# desktop application. I add my icon to my application but when I install the software, the shortcut icon on desktop is different from the original. I post 2 images that explain the situation.

This is my icon:
[image: This is my icon]

..but this is how the shortcut icon looks
[image: This is how shortcut icon look: there are those 2 arrows on the top-right corner that aren't on the original icon]

There are those 2 arrows on the top-right corner that aren't on the original icon

What can I do to fix this? I followed a video-tutorial on Youtube and I do the same operations but in the video the icon is right.

Comment: The blue arrows are an overlay added by explorer in certain situations, such as those [involving NTFS compression](http://superuser.com/questions/1001970/two-blue-arrows-at-top-right-of-icons) (probably of the extracted shortcut icon file Christopher discusses).

Comment: Ok, but how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are doing an advertised shortcut, InstallShield will extract icon resource 0 from the EXE.  So this would all come down to how you built your EXE.

If you aren't doing an advertised shortcut (not sure if ISLE supports this)  then the shortcut doesn't have an icon and Windows will resolve it from the EXE when it renders the screen.

Comment: How can I do a not-advertised shortcut?

Comment: I don't know if you can or not in ISLE.  I don't currently have it installed anywhere.  Take a look at the screen that defines the shortcut and see if there is a Boolean property for Advertised.

Comment: I don't find anything like that but I sure I can do id ISLE because int the tutorial that I saw the user was using this version.

Comment: According to a screenshot in this tutorial it only does advertised shortcuts but yo can specify the icon resource index # to use.  Try a different number. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/